# Fancybox (Ajax) not working in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, fancybox, fancybox-2

My site works great in Chrome/Firefox, but pulls up a small white box in the middle of the page on IE8.

**Note:** I have gone to the **[demo site](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)** with IE8 and the ajax call works fine. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

**This is the script I'm using to initiate Fancybox...**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        // Change title type, overlay closing speed
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What version of jquery?

Comment: And again, it works on all browsers (except IE8), and it works on mobile devices, too...

Comment: You have at the end more scripts, disable one by one and see which disturbs Fancybox... and play around to put the script-link from Fancybox to the bottom.....

Comment: I disabled all the scripts and nothing changed with Fancybox. Moved the .js file to the end - Nothing. Moved the initialization script to the end of the body - Nothing... The only other thing I can think of is a JSON script, but there isn't one with Fancybox.

Comment: Please stop linking to external sites in your questions. Your question needs to be completely self-contained, it cannot depend on external links to be answerable.

Comment: @meager - If you review my question history, you'll see this is rarely done. As a very last resort, I use external sites. In this case, I could not replicate the error in a demo site such as jsFiddle or CodePen. I do know how to use this site very well and have always corrected myself where I have fallen short of the documentation provided by SO. I've always trusted SO to be a great provider of assistance when I'm at my whit's end. So, if not some type of example, then what do you suggest to replicate the error.

Comment: FYI - Providing my example helped Mike Vranckx assist me. His potential solution worked. In many cases, those browsing SO don't necessarily need an example to go by, but maybe the description of someone's problem matches mine...therefore, the solution may also assist the next person... which is all that really matters, right?

Comment: Why the continued downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the HTML of your ajax content pages, it seems that is not W3C valid. Internet Explorer 8 probably does some validation on that ...

Remove the extra closing `</div>` at the end.

Verified this page: http://webfro.gs/south/tour3579/ajax/associate-ba.html

Comment: I did it. Ran it through the validator again. I even added the missing `alt=""` tags and still nothing. It's a 100% compliant page. I don't get it. The [**demo Fancybox site**](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples) works fine in IE8, just not mine.

Comment: Seems to be working now on my IE8 after the HTML correction. Visit directly your ajax content URL and do a hard refresh (CTRL + F5) to force a reload (otherwise you may get a cached older page version)

Answer (score 0):

Some js errors may prevent fancybox from working, specially with IE which is less tolerant than other browsers.

In your case the [zoomflow.js](http://webfro.gs/south/tour3579/zoomflow/zoomflow.js) file has many `console.log` commands that are not valid within the IE context therefore they trigger js errors.

Example :

```
console.log("this demo doesn't work in IE");
$(".fancybox").fancybox();
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/J6Cfh/show/)**; works fine in most modern browsers but IE[7-9]